# Getting toolBar elevation in dark mode with material styles (PrimarySurface)

Tags: android, android-styles, material-components-android, darkmode

According to [Material documents](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark) you could use "PrimarySurface" styles for components like toolbar and tab layout to switch their background color between color Primary and Surface in light mode and dark mode for android 10 and higher. This is my styles xml file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="LightCustomFontStyle">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/toolbarStyle</item>

</style>


<style name="toolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface"/>
```

And [dark mode elevation](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#properties) is supposed to be displayed with lighter colors but the thing is that colorSurface and colorBackground have the same value(#121212) and so in dark mode if you use these two at the same time, your toolbar won't display any elevation in relation to your activity.

It will look like this but I need it to look like the toolbar in Material docs. Also setting elevation for the toolbar doesn't work.

Is there anyway to get the elevated toolbar(lighter color) with Material and google styles or I should just set the lighter colors manually?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [doc](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark/):

> in a dark theme the elevation overlays are semi-transparent white (`colorOnSurface`) overlays that are conceptually placed on top of the surface color.

The overlay is based on the `colorOnSurface` defined in the app theme.
You can change this color adding in the app theme:

```
<item name="elevationOverlayColor">@color/...</item>
```